# Redirect http to https with Node/Express

Tags: node.js, ssl, express, https, parse-platform

I have a website hosted with Parse.com. It runs on Node.js/Express.js 3. I am just trying to force https if somebody visits the domain with http. Possible?

They have some documentation, but I'm not sure how to apply it:
https://parse.com/docs/js/symbols/parseExpressHttpsRedirect.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It describes exactly how to use it on that page:

> To use this middleware, you must require it from your JavaScript file:
>
> var parseExpressHttpsRedirect = require('parse-express-https-redirect');
>
> Then you can use the middleware to redirect all requests to HTTPS.
>
> app.use(parseExpressHttpsRedirect());

So in code:

```
var parseExpressHttpsRedirect = require('parse-express-https-redirect');

// ... later on when you're initializing your express app ...
app.use(parseExpressHttpsRedirect());
```

Comment: You are correct! The problem was I was deploying to the wrong App! D'oh!

Comment: Hmmm... so this particular app doesn't run Express. It's just a static website. So app.js doesn't appear to be doing any work. How do serve a static website to make this work?

Comment: Ah, that means that you're not using Node.js/Express to serve the files. What webserver is it? Apache/IIS/nginx/etc.?

Comment: It's hosted with Parse.com